# Generic class inherit from Dictionary with Collection

Tags: c#, generics

I have this custom Dictionary with Collection definition:

```
class CollectionDictionary<K, C, V> : Dictionary<K, C> where C : ICollection<V>, new()
```

and using it like this (e.g):

```
CollectionDictionary<Guid, HashSet<int>, int> sample;
```

but for me this double `int` seems awkward, is there a possibility to bypass this and only write:

```
CollectionDictionary<Guid, HashSet<int>> sample;
```

so that the compiler knows that `V` could only be an int?

**EDIT:**

I need the class to abstract this method

```
public void Add(K key, V value)
{
    if (!this.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        base.Add(key, new C());
    }
    this[key].Add(value);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [MultiValueDictionary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary.aspx) ? It's a dictionary that allows multiple values per key and returns an IEnumerable of the values

Comment: No this isn't possible.

Comment: yes like that, but I need to specify the type of the Collection (e.g. Set or List)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok I see, they have a possibility to use HashSets but also with a complicated way: `MultiValueDictionary<string, int>.Create<HashSet<int>>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
class CollectionDictionary<K, C> : Dictionary<K, ICollection<C>>
```

It removes the constraint you had that makes the `ICollection` have an empty constructor.

In order to be able to create new collections you could ask for a delegate that does that. But in your case I think your original solution would produce less boilerplate code.

```
// ctor
public CollectionDictionary(Func<ICollection<C>> collectionCreator)

// Create
base.Add(key, _collectionCreator());

// Init
new CollectionDictionary<Guid, int>(() => new HashSet<int>());
```

Comment: Not _technically_ the same at the OPs definition, but may meet all of the requirements.

Comment: This doesn't *exactly* mirror the behavior in the OP, since it allows you to have two `CollectionDictionary<Guid,int>` instances where one is based on a `Hashset<int>` and the other on a `List<int>`, but yeah, for most practical considerations, probably good enough.

Comment: sorry, but I need to instantiate new Collection objects, will add a method to my question

Comment: @JanS Edited with a solution to that, but I think your original approach is better if that is the case.

Comment: @MotiAzu accepted cause it solves the problem, although the original approach is better